# R cannot be resolved android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estou enfrentando um problema, parece ser um pouco simples, mas já estou a algumas horas com isso.

Estou montando um projeto no android Studio e o Mesmo esta dando no campo `private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null`;

```
// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_);`
```

na linha `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_)` o R Fica em vermelho e não compila o projeto.

ja procurei vários tutoriais incluindo o que os que falam para ir em Build > **Clean** e em **Rebuild**, também revisei o Project Struture mas sem sucesso

Alguém saberia me informar o que pode ser isso 
Desde ja fico muito agradecido

Comment: Colocar a cursor de escrita ao lado do R, da um alt + enter e veja se aparece a opção de importar, se sim, só clica nela e pronto

Comment: Agora quando é criado uma nova activity, ele não faz o importe automaticamente

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente tenho esse tipo de erro quando existe algum erro nos arquivos xml, verifique-os e depois recompile seu projeto.

PS: O Eclipse Android não aceita letras maiúsculas em nomes de arquivos XML, não tenho certeza se o android studio tem o mesmo procedimento, mas vale a tentativa.